# TouchPhase.Ended not executing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Working in a mobile controller and I'm having an interesting issue. When I press left and right fast and then jump then the character keeps on walking to either right or left direction making me think that moveLeft or moveRight never get sets to false in some instances.

I read a lot of posts talking about TouchPhase.Ended not firing, have you guys experience this? is there a solution?

Edited my post and included my code guys:

```
void Update(){
    TouchManager ();
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    Move ();
}

void Move ()
{
    //True if player hits ground
    groundHit = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
    //True if player hits top
    topHit = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (topCheck.position, topRadius, whatIsTop);
    anim.SetBool ("Ground", groundHit);
    anim.SetFloat ("vSpeed", this.rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    if (Globals.gameStatus == Globals.GameStatus.Dead) {
        anim.SetFloat ("Speed", 0);
        return;
    }
    float move = 0.0f;

    if (moveLeft) {
        move = -1.0f;
    }
    if (moveRight) {
        move = 1.0f;
    }

    anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (move));

    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, this.rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    if (move > 0 && !facingRight)
        Flip ();
    else
        if (move < 0 && facingRight)
            Flip ();
}

void TouchManager ()
{

    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        var touchCount = Input.touchCount;
        for (var i = 0; i < touchCount; i++) {
            var touch = Input.GetTouch (i);
            //Debug.Log("FingerID: " + touch.fingerId.ToString());

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                //Debug.Log("Touch Began executed for touchID: " + touch.
                if (guiLeft.HitTest (touch.position, Camera.main))
                    moveLeft = true;
                if (guiRight.HitTest (touch.position, Camera.main))
                    moveRight = true;
                if (guiJump.HitTest (touch.position, Camera.main))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Jump pressed");
                    if (groundHit  && !stickmanIsDead) {
                        anim.SetBool ("Ground", false);
                        rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpForce));
                    }
                    //Record start time only once
                    holdJumpDownStartedAt = Time.time;
                }
            }
            //Fall from Platforms
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary){
                if (guiJump.HitTest (touch.position, Camera.main)){
                    if(Time.time - holdJumpDownStartedAt > dropPlatformAt){
                        Debug.Log(string.Format("Holded for {0} second :) ",dropPlatformAt.ToString()));
                        holdJumpDownStartedAt = 0.0f;

                        #region Falling Keystroke
                        var playerFalling = Physics2D.Linecast (transform.position, groundCheck.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Floor-Air"));
                        //Fall Key
                        if (playerFalling)
                            StartCoroutine (Fall ());
                        #endregion
                    }
                }
            }
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled){
                if (guiLeft.HitTest (touch.position, Camera.main))
                    moveLeft = false;
                if (guiRight.HitTest (touch.position, Camera.main))
                    moveRight = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your particular code? There are indeed cases where TouchPhase.Ended reportedly doesn't fire (what is the platform you're on btw) but more often than not it's the actual code that's an issue.

Comment: perhaps TouchPhase.Canceled is being triggered instead of Ended? But without any code, we can't really help. Are there buttons for left and right? Are they gui buttons?

Comment: Just added my code see my post. Thanks for responding so quickly. There are three buttons, left and right and also Jump. See my code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out guys thanks anyways here's what I ended up doing:

`void CharacterTouchManager (){`

```
    //Debug.Log("Moving..." + rigidbody2D.velocity.x.ToString());
    //Debug.Log("Player is: " + Globals.playIsDoing.ToString());

    //Movement 
    if(Input.touchCount > 0){
        var touchCount = Input.touchCount;
        for (var i = 0; i < touchCount; i++) {
            var touch = Input.GetTouch (i);
            //if player presses less than 1/5 of the screen, go left.
            if(touch.position.x < Screen.width / 5 && touch.position.y < Screen.height / 3){
                touchControlSwitchToJumpMode = false;
                //if(rigidbody2D.velocity.x > -0.1){
                //  moveLeft = true;
                //}
                //else 
                //  moveLeft = true;

                moveLeft = true;
                moveRight = false;
            }
            //if player presses between 1/5 and 2/5 of the screen, go right.
            if(touch.position.x > Screen.width / 5 && touch.position.x < Screen.width / 5 * 2 && touch.position.y < Screen.height / 3){
                touchControlSwitchToJumpMode = false;

                //if(rigidbody2D.velocity.x < 0.1){
                //  moveRight = true;
                //}
                moveRight = true;
                moveLeft = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        moveLeft = moveRight = false;
    }

    //Jumping and Dropping from platforms
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        var touchCount = Input.touchCount;
        for (var i = 0; i < touchCount; i++) {
            var touch = Input.GetTouch (i);
            //Make sure we're not touching jump by itself to avoid character running continously
            if(!touchControlSwitchToJumpMode && touchCount == 1 && guiJump.HitTest (touch.position, Camera.main)){
                moveRight = moveLeft = false;
                touchControlSwitchToJumpMode = true;
            }
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                if (guiJump.HitTest (touch.position, Camera.main))
                {
                    if (groundHit  && !stickmanIsDead) {
                        anim.SetBool ("Ground", false);
                        rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpForce));
                    }
                    //Record start time only once
                    holdJumpDownStartedAt = Time.time;
                }
            }
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary){
                if (guiJump.HitTest (touch.position, Camera.main)){
                    if(Time.time - holdJumpDownStartedAt > dropPlatformAt){
                        holdJumpDownStartedAt = 0.0f;
                        #region Falling Keystroke
                        var playerFalling = Physics2D.Linecast (transform.position, groundCheck.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Floor-Air"));
                        //Fall Key
                        if (playerFalling)
                            StartCoroutine (Fall ());
                        #endregion
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```